# Database organization for separating two different types of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationships, database-relations

So I want my User model to have_many Skills. I want there to be two different categories for the skills: a wanted skill, and a possessed skill.

For example, a user can add a skill to their profile that they possess, such as HTML. They can also add a skill to their profile that they wish to learn, such as Ruby on Rails. On their profile it'll list their current skills and wanted ones, separately.

From a high level, what's the best way to architect this? I just want there to be 1 Skill model with no duplicates, but I want there to be a way for users to have the 2 separate groups of skills in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single table inheritance

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class WantedSkill < Skill
   belongs_to :user
end

class PossessesSkill < Skill
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Your skills table should have a column called `type` where the type of the skill will be stored.

```
WantedSkill.create(:name => "html")
```

Above will save the record in the skills table with type 'WantedSkill'. You can retrieve it by

```
WantedSkill.where(:name => "html").first
```

your user associations can be like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :wanted_skills
   has_many :possessed_skills
end
```

You can read documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)

Answer (score 1):

A way to achieve this, you need two *skill* fields like: `wanted_skill` and `possessed_skill`

So, in Ruby on Rails you can have many references (with different names) to the same model, you only need to declare which class corresponds using `class_name` in the references, e.g.:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :wanted_skill, class_name: 'Skill'
  belongs_to :possessed_skill, class_name: 'Skill'
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't I want to do has_many :wanted_skill, class_name: 'Skill'
instead of belongs_to?

Comment: Yes, but `belongs_to` makes more sense to your code, using this only one skill can be associated to each field, if you want more than one, you need a [many-to-many relationship](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)